# Positioning Javascript Tag on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm growing frustrated in positioning my javascript date in the center of my html page. Everything else is centered but the javascript date.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<section>
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhills.ccsf.edu%2F~avu%2Fhw1.html" target="_blank"><img id="html5logo"src="images/html5_logo.png" alt="html5" height="50" width="50" /></a>

<a href="http://alturl.com/9kv4o" target="_blank"><img id="csslogo" src="images/css_logo.gif" alt="css" height="50" width="50" /></a>
</section>

<br />

<p id="pagelastupdated">Page last updated:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(document.lastModified);
</script>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
section  {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 112px;
}

section img#html5logo  {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

section img#csslogo  {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#pagelastupdated  {
    text-align: center;
}

script  {
    border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: I noticed you tried to etyle the script tag, do you want a purple border around the date?

Answer (score 2):

You might try (adjusted to show two lines)

```
<p align="center" id="pagelastupdated">Page last updated:<br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(document.lastModified);
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: ErstwhileIII has it right.

But, I want to have that <script> underneath "Page last updated:"

Anyway to do that?

Comment: @user3385997 the last updated text is not going to be in the script tag. Right click on it an select Inspect element and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the end paragraph tag to after the end script tag, or writing the date to the document wrapped in a div and then centre that.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the date outside of the `p` tag, which is the one which you are centering.